Avoid/Clear UrlFetchApp cache when fetching a RSS feedin Google Script
I encounter a problem on Google Apps Script.
The use of the script is to get RSS feed URLs to fetch from a Google Sheet and if new article(s) are detected (comparing the GUIDs from the fetch to a GUID array stored locally), post them in a Google Chat space.
The problem faced is when I fetch the RSS feed URL. The result is the version of the day before, until it fetches the new version once after 45 to 60 minutes after the publication. Most of the time it comes back to the previous version and alternate between the outdated and good versions.
I precise that I use a time based trigger.
I am sure about the delay with the new version since I check it manually several times a day the RSS feed to check the script health.
Logs :
11 Jun 2024, 15:37:05  =>  lastBuildDate : Mon, 10 Jun 2024 13:06:32 +0000
11 Jun 2024, 15:39:21  =>  lastBuildDate : Tue, 11 Jun 2024 12:46:24 +0000
11 Jun 2024, 15:49:28  =>  lastBuildDate : Mon, 10 Jun 2024 13:06:32 +0000
Here is the code used in a function called for all lines in the Google Sheets detected :
var xml,document = null;
var fetchOptions = {
  "async": true,
  "method": "GET",
  "contentType": "application/xml",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "followRedirects": true,
  headers : {
    'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
    'Clear-Site-Data' : '*', 
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoging" : "gzip, deflate, br"
  }
}

try{
  var now = new Date().getTime()**2;
  var url = FEED_URL + "?t=" + now;
  Logger.log("Fetching this url : " + url);
  //Add the now timestamp to the URL to avoid cached versions
  xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchOptions).getContentText();
  document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  //Log the last build date and the latest item found
  Logger.log("lastBuildDate : " + document.getRootElement().getChild("channel").getChild("lastBuildDate").getText());
  };

As you can see in the script shown above, I have tried to :

Assign xml and document variables to null to "reset" these.
Add 'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0' or 'max-age=1' or 'no-cache' or 'no-store' but non of those options had an impact.
Add the timestamp on power 2 as a parameter to the end of the URL to try to fetch a "new" URL every time (in fact the same result)

None of these options have worked, I get old versions for 45 minutes every time still.
Is there a way to clear or avoid the cache from the UrlFetchApp from Google Apps Script ?

Are you sure UrlFetchApp is the problem? Could you identify a specific instance where fetch returned a different page than when you manually enter the same url in the browser? I highly doubt the problem is in Urlfetchapp. It has no built-in cache function.

Yes, sorry for the delay I waited for the daily update of the RSS feed.
Here is the result of this command $ date && curl -s "https://www.cert.ssi.gouv.fr/avis/feed/" : Wed Jun 12 03:32:02 PM CEST 2024 ...
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 12 Jun 2024 13:15:59 +0000</lastBuildDate>
And here are the logs of the executions that occured on Jun 12 2024, 15:32:39 : lastBuildDate : Tue, 11 Jun 2024 12:46:24 +0000
I double checked the URL fetched, it is not a miswrite or something like that.

@TheMaster The new version was detected: Jun 12 2024, 15:48:42 => lastBuildDate : Wed, 12 Jun 2024 13:15:59 +0000

I still think it's a server issue. Maybe try logging date && curl -s "https://www.cert.ssi.gouv.fr/avis/feed/" | rg 'lastBuildDate[^<]*<' -o every 1 minute or so. If that doesn't reproduce the same error, maybe the server is offering differing versions based on ip? May be Google's ip is configured to serve older version from the server?  I don't think this is an issue on Urlfetchapp. If however, you think it is, you can create a bug report on the issue tracker, which gets you in contact with Google devs(See tag info page for links)

This method locally result in this output : Thu 13 Jun 2024 03:16:35 PM CEST <lastBuildDate>Wed, 12 Jun 2024 14:48:49 +0000</lastBuildDate>                 Thu 13 Jun 2024 03:17:35 PM CEST <lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Jun 2024 12:56:22 +0000</lastBuildDate>            Thu 13 Jun 2024 03:18:35 PM CEST <lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Jun 2024 12:56:22 +0000</lastBuildDate> Thu 13 Jun 2024 03:19:35 PM CEST <lastBuildDate>Wed, 12 Jun 2024 14:48:49 +0000</lastBuildDate>                    Thu 13 Jun 2024 03:21:35 PM CEST <lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Jun 2024 12:56:22 +0000</lastBuildDate>

This method on App Scirt resulted in this :
15:20:47 Infos <lastBuildDate>Wed, 12 Jun 2024 14:48:49 +0000</lastBuildDate> 15:21:47 Infos <lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Jun 2024 12:56:22 +0000</lastBuildDate>
